# How do I write 'input[type="radio"]:checked + label' inside state in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, input, css-selectors

I have the following selectors in my CSS file:

```
input[type="radio"]:checked + label.true {
  background: #94D7A2;
  border: none
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label.false {
  background: #F8BCBC;
  border: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

But I need to change the background on the click of another button (not the inputs), so I wanted to put this inside my component using state, like so:

```
.... other code here ....

const [styling, setStyling] = useReact({})

function handleClick() {
  setStyling({
    input[type="radio"]:checked + label.true {
      background: #94D7A2;
      border: none
    },
    input[type="radio"]:checked + label.false {
      background: #F8BCBC;
      border: none;
      opacity: 0.5;
    }
  })
}

.... other code here ....

<input type="radio" id="radio1" style={${correct_answer === answer ? "true" : "false"}}>
<label htmlFor="radio1">Choice 1</label> // this is what I want to update

<button onClick={handleClick}>Check</button> // this is the button I want to activate the change of the state
```

Does this make sense? Basically what I need is to:

- conditionally update the  element with a .true or .false class
- but I only want that styling to be visible once I click the "Check" button, so I need to change the state on click

This all works great when the styling is in my separate CSS file, but since I need to update it on click, I need it to be inside my component.

Comment: Switch classes (checked, unchecked) on the input and keep the styles in a separate style sheet mapped to these classes

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can give you a start, to see how to use module css look here: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/

```
import { useRef, useState } from "react"

const questionList = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "What is the correct answer?",
    options: [
      { text: "Wrong", correct: false },
      { text: "Right", correct: true },
      { text: "Wrong", correct: false }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "And now which is the correct one?",
    options: [
      { text: "Right", correct: true },
      { text: "Wrong", correct: false },
      { text: "Wrong", correct: false }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Can you choose the right option?",
    options: [
      { text: "Wrong", correct: true },
      { text: "Wrong", correct: false },
      { text: "Right", correct: true }
    ]
  }
]

export const Option = ({ option, showCorrectAnswers, questionId, answers, index }) => {

  const correctAnswerStyle = { background: "#94D7A2" }
  const wrongAnswerStyle = {
    background: "#F8BCBC",
    opacity: 0.5
  }

  const inputRef = useRef();
  const id = `question_${questionId}_option${index}`;

  const getStyle = () => {
    if (!showCorrectAnswers) return {};

    if (inputRef.current.checked && option.correct) return correctAnswerStyle;

    return wrongAnswerStyle;
  }

  const handleClick = () => {
    answers[questionId] = 1;
  }

  return <div style={getStyle()}>
    <input id={id} onClick={handleClick} ref={inputRef} type="radio" name={`question_${questionId}`} />
    <label htmlFor={id}>{option.text}</label>
  </div>;
}

export const Question = ({ question, showCorrectAnswers, answers }) => {

  return <div>
    <p>{question.title}</p>
    {question.options.map((option, index) =>
      <Option key={`question_${question.id}_${index}`}
        questionId={question.id}
        option={option}
        showCorrectAnswers={showCorrectAnswers}
        answers={answers}
        index={index} />)
    }
  </div>
}

export const Quiz = ({ questionList }) => {
  const [showCorrectAnswers, setShowCorrectAnswers] = useState(false);
  const [answers] = useState({});
  const errorMsgRef = useRef();

  const handleCheck = () => {
    if (Object.keys(answers).length != questionList.length) {
      errorMsgRef.current.innerHTML = "Please, answer all questions";
      return;
    }

    errorMsgRef.current.innerHTML = "";
    setShowCorrectAnswers(true);
  }

  return <div>
    {questionList.map(question =>
      <Question key={`question_${question.id}`}
        question={question}
        showCorrectAnswers={showCorrectAnswers}
        answers={answers} />)
    }
    <button onClick={handleCheck} >Check</button>
    <p ref={errorMsgRef}></p>
  </div>
}

export default function App() {
  return <Quiz questionList={questionList} />;
}
```